# String 'Y' to true and 'N' to false in Java

Tags: java, java-8

Is there any library in Java to convert a string "Y" to true or "N" to false?

I did an enum but I don't know if it is the best way:

```
public enum BooleanEnum {

    TRUE("Y"), FALSE("F");

    private String booleanValue;

    private BooleanEnum(String booleanValue) {
        this.booleanValue = booleanValue;
    }

    public String getBooleanValue() {
        return booleanValue;
    }

}
```

And to use:

```
if (BooleanEnum.TRUE.getBooleanValue().equals(cpoPipelineDTO.getCpoPipelineCategory().getIsDataFlow())) {
```

Comment: What is the data type of `IsDataFlow` ?  Is better to use BooleanEnum as IsDataFlow data type.

Comment: String - "Y" or "N" @Eklavya

Comment: Why would you need a library for such a simple function?

Comment: Why not @DorianGray?

Comment: I would rather want to avoid dependencies on 3rd party libraries if it is such a simple task.

Comment: I didn't add any extra dependency in my project because commons-lang is already available by another library.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [BooleanUtils.toBooleanObject()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/BooleanUtils.html#toBooleanObject-java.lang.String-) or [BooleanUtils.toBoolean()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/BooleanUtils.html#toBoolean-java.lang.String-) of `org.apache.commons.lang3`

```
BooleanUtils.toBoolean("Y")   = true
BooleanUtils.toBoolean("N")   = false
BooleanUtils.toBooleanObject("Y") = Boolean.TRUE
BooleanUtils.toBooleanObject("N") = Boolean.FALSE
```

And you can also convert boolean value to string also

```
BooleanUtils.toString( booleanVal ,"Y", "N")
```